# saving data of EDITTEXT field in

Tags: android, database, android-edittext

I have two user screens in my app. In the first screen i have two `EditText` fields. One takes a string and another an int. I click on the save button to save the values in the database. now the problem that i get is that `NULL` is being saved into the database. when I hard code it, the values get saved. Anyone has any idea as to why is this happening.

this is what i am trying to do with code:

```
EditText userNameTextField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.savehighscoresid);
userNameString = userNameTextField.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `userNameTextField.getText().toString() == null;`. If yes, disable your save button. Add a textChangedListner to check if text is getting added in that box

```
userNameTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            charachtercounter1.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userNameTextField.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
    value = String.valueOf(userNameTextField.getText());
}
```

Try this..Where value is String..